# http.Server Serve method hangs when calling Shutdown immediately

Tags: http, go, server, synchronization, goroutine

I have an issue with Go's http.Server, which I'm embedding in a struct that is supposed to control the server startup and shutdown. The struct looks like this:

```
type HTTPListen struct {
    Consumers []pipeline.Consumer
    Cfg       HTTPListenConfig
    Srv       *http.Server
    Logger    log.Logger
    wg        *sync.WaitGroup
    mu        sync.Mutex
    state     State
}
```

The issue is that in my test code, I call my struct's `Start()` method (which in turn runs the `Serve()` method on the http.Server), check a few vars, and then call `Stop()`, whitch `Shutdown()`s the server and then waits for the http.Server to exit (return `err` from the `Serve()` method).

Now, for some reason, the `Serve()` method seems to just hang on the `WaitGroup.Wait()`, when I try to shutdown the server immediately after starting. When I add a short pause (tried 100ms), or when running the tests with the race detector, It works just fine.

Not sure if it matters, but there are no incoming requests between calling `Serve()` and `Shutdown()`.

**EDIT:** [link to a playground minimal example](https://play.golang.org/p/s1jCfE44c3). If you comment out the `time.Sleep` call, the program hangs.

Here is the relevant code for the two methods:

```
func (h *HTTPListen) Start() error {

    h.Logger.Log("msg", "starting HTTPListen input")

    addr := h.Cfg.ListenAddr
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        h.Logger.Log("msg", "failed to create listener on tcp/"+addr+": "+err.Error())
        h.setState(StateFailed)
        return err
    }

    h.wg.Add(1)
    go func() {

        defer h.wg.Done()
        err := h.Srv.Serve(ln)
        h.Logger.Log("msg", "HTTP server stopped: "+err.Error())

    }()

    h.setState(StateStarted)
    h.Logger.Log("msg", "HTTPListen input started")

    return nil

}
```

Stop method:

```
func (h *HTTPListen) Stop() error {

    h.Logger.Log("msg", "stopping HTTPListen input")

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
    defer cancel()

    if err := h.Srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        h.Logger.Log("msg", "HTTP server shutdown deadline expired")
    }

    h.wg.Wait()

    h.setState(StateStopped)
    h.Logger.Log("msg", "HTTPListen input stopped")

    return nil
}
```

Log output:

```
kwz@cyclone ~/s/stblogd> go test -v ./pkg/pipeline/input/ -run TestHTTPListen_StartStop
=== RUN   TestHTTPListen_StartStop
msg="starting HTTPListen input"
msg="HTTPListen input started"
msg="stopping HTTPListen input"
... hangs indefinitely
```

Log output when running tests with the race detector:

```
kwz@cyclone ~/s/stblogd> go test -race -v ./pkg/pipeline/input/ -run TestHTTPListen_StartStop
=== RUN   TestHTTPListen_StartStop
msg="starting HTTPListen input"
msg="HTTPListen input started"
msg="stopping HTTPListen input"
msg="HTTP server stopped: http: Server closed"
msg="HTTPListen input stopped"
--- PASS: TestHTTPListen_StartStop (0.00s)
PASS
ok      stblogd/pkg/pipeline/input      1.007s
```

I'm tempted to just slap a short delay on the test and call it a day, but I would like to know why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, see this thread:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20239

Hopefully they will fix it soon but for now it sounds like adding a short delay in your test is the simplest solution - it probably doesn't come up in real world use much because you won't trigger a shutdown so soon after starting.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply and link. Yeah, this won't be a problem in a real run, but I wanted to make sure I'm not ignoring something that could break later.

Thanks again!

Comment: For me this didn't help, I call shutdown or close hours after starting to serve, and the calling routine hangs and the listener remains active